# Firebase FieldValue.arrayUnion() not working properly on client SDK

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to create an array in firestore with this code

```
await store
    .collection("video")
    .doc(videoId)
    .set(
      {
        data: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId),
      },
      {merge: true},
    )
```

The data created in firestore then look like

[image: this]

Answer (score 1):

This behavior appear because I was using firestore from @react-native-firebase/firestore and importing firebase from firebase library instead of @react-native-firebase/app so i had to change this

```
import firebase from "firebase"
```

To this

```
import firebase from "@react-native-firebase/app"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, omit the trailing comma after `{merge:true}`.

If that doesn't fix it, can you share how you define "userId" and "store"?